# Setting environment variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I'm trying to make my project OSS, and I'd like to remove any sensitive info from the configs. I'm trying to have `ENV['DB_PASS'] = mypassword`. Where would I set this? I've tried `export DB_PASS=mypassword` in my .bashrc file. But that's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `export` isn't working?  Have you tried `echo $DB_PASS`?  (Also, changes to .bashrc won't take effect until the next time you log in.)

A more common way to handle this problem is to create a separate config file that is not tracked in your repository, and then provide a `config.sample` file demonstrating the common configuration options but with dummy values.

Comment: I ended up using your suggested method and just used capistrano to symlink the file to the release dir.